# How to create CNN model using keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, model-fitting

I want to create one CNN model including all nSeizures models instead of creating model for each seizure file, but i got this error < AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fit_generator'>.

```
for i in range(0, nSeizure):
            print(nSeizure)
            print('SEIZURE OUT: '+str(i+1))
            print('Training start') 
           ## create model
            model = createModel()
            filesPath=getFilesPathWithoutSeizure(i, indexPat)
           ## create one model including all nSeizures models
            for model in range(0, nSeizure):
                mylist.append(model)
                data=mylist.append(model)
                history=data.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75), 
                                validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, 
                                start=75),
                                #steps_per_epoch=10000, epochs=10)
                                steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*25))), 
                                validation_steps=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*75))),
                                verbose=2,
                                epochs=300, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[callback])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mylist.append(model)` returns None.
when you call `data.fit_generator` it effectively means `None.fit_generator`.
Consider rewriting the code.